# get last week in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following in a script:

```
var startDate = new Date("10/12/2012");
var endDate = new Date("10/18/2012");
```

I would like those dates to be dynamically created with startDate as last Monday and endDate as last Sunday. I have tried the following:

```
var curr = new Date; // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6
var startDate = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).format("m/dd/yyyy");
var endDate = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).format("m/dd/yyyy");
```

But for some reason this doesn't work - nothing is outputted for the startDate or endDate variables.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please define what "this doesn't work" means.

Comment: Do you mean "the Monday before last"? So you're trying to get the Monday-> Sunday span preceding the current week?

Comment: Kiyura - yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javascript datetime object does not have a format method. You'll need to use a library or generate the string yourself:

```
var curr = new Date; // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6
var startDate = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
startDate = "" + (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + startDate.getDate() + "/" + startDate.getFullYear();
var endDate = new Date(curr.setDate(last));
endDate = "" + (endDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + endDate.getDate() + "/" + endDate.getFullYear();
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DPQeB/2/ and its output

> 11/18/2012
>   11/24/2012

One library that allows you to format dates is [jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate).

Answer (score 2):

Using [**date.js**](http://www.datejs.com/) to get last Sunday

```
Date.today().moveToDayOfWeek(0, -1); // -1 indicates to go back
```

Best to use a library to manipulate dates. It will make your life a lot easier.

Having said that have a long-term aim to understand dates in JavaScript. It will help you with things like debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If starting from sunday:

```
var today = new Date();
var sundayOfWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - today.getDay()-8);
var mondayOfWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - today.getDay()+1);

console.log( mondayOfWeek );
console.log( sundayOfWeek );
```