# how to calculate salary of last week in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jaggery-js

I'm trying to calculate salary of last week of employees. It means current week should not me included in the calculation. Right now I have -7 from current date to check my data. This is my code

```
var currentDate = new Date();
log.info(currentDate)
var requiredDate=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-7)
var start=Date.parse(requiredDate)
var end=Date.parse(currentDate);
query="taskCreateTimestamp:["+start+" TO "+end+"]";
```

My objective is to calculate last week salary between Monday to friday. I have taken -7 to check my data only. Please help me

Comment: Your question is "how to validate timestamp is monday, tuesday wednesday or some other day in javascript?" and in code you are asking to  to calculate salary of last week exaclty hat you want in result

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. I need to calculate last week salary only. @mean

Comment: So finally you want current date and from 7the previous day from now am i right?

Comment: Do you want to calculate what data range was on last week? So then you calculate the salary?

Comment: @sam you areready getting current date and 7th day from current day then where ou are getting stuck ?

Comment: Right now I'm getting calculation of last 7days where as I want to calculate it of last week from monday to friday. @mean

Answer (score 0):

check this link you can get start date and end date of last week.
and append time stamp '00:00:00' to start date and '23:59:59' to the end date if your data have time stamp.

[get last week in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493569/get-last-week-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

"(salary / (working days of month)) * (working days of last week)"
Above line should be your formula for calculating last week salary. So, you need a method which calculates working days of given date interval.

```
function getWorkingDays(startDate, endDate){
    var totalWorkingDays= 0;
    var currentDate = startDate;
    while (currentDate <= endDate)  {
        var weekDay = currentDate.getDay();
        if(weekDay != 0 && weekDay != 6) {
            totalWorkingDays++;
        }
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1); 
    }
    return totalWorkingDays;
}
```

Then, give the dates and apply the formula.

Comment: My objective is to calculate only salary of last week. If today is monday it sholud not include current day. as well as calculate salary of monday to friday.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code in Jaggeryjs and working fine for me. I haven't tested yet but getting expected result.

```
 var currentDate = new Date();
    var requiredDate;
    log.info(currentDate)
    var set=currentDate.setHours(0)
    if(currentDate.getDay() == 1)
    {
     requiredDate=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-7)
    }
    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 2)
    {
     requiredDate=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-8)
    }
    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 3)
    {
     requiredDate=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-9)
    }
    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 4)
    {
     requiredDate=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-10)
    }
    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 5)
    {
     requiredDate=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-4)
    }
    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 6)
    {
     requiredDate=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-5)
    }
    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 7)
    {
     requiredDate=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-6)
    }
    var start=Date.parse(requiredDate)
    log.info("Start-Date["+start+"]")         
    log.info("End----------------------------------------------")
    var currentDate = new Date();
    log.info(currentDate)       
    var end;
    if(currentDate.getDay() == 7)
    {
     end=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-2)
    }
    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 6)
    {
     end=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-1)
    }

    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 5)
    {
     end=Date.parse(currentDate)
     log.info("End Date ["+end+"]")
    }
    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 4)
    {
     end=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-6)
    }
    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 3)
    {
     end=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-5)
    }
    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 2)
    {
     end=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-4)
    }
    else if(currentDate.getDay() == 1)
    {
     end=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate()-3)
    }


    end=Date.parse(currentDate);
    log.info("End-Date["+end+"]")         
    query="taskCreateTimestamp:["+start+" TO "+end+"]";
```