# How get range of current week date like this format (March 20.2017)?

Tags: javascript

- March 20.2017  (Monday)
- March 21.2017 (Tuesday)
- March 22.2017 (Wednesday)
- March 23.2017 (Thursday)
- ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [date.js](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) library. Such things you should do yourself

The cdn path of the library: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js

```js
var date= Date.monday().toString('MMMM dd.yyyy')
date += "\n"+Date.tuesday().toString('MMMM dd.yyyy')
date += "\n"+Date.wednesday().toString('MMMM dd.yyyy')
date += "\n"+Date.thursday().toString('MMMM dd.yyyy')
date += "\n"+Date.friday().toString('MMMM dd.yyyy')
date += "\n"+Date.saturday().toString('MMMM dd.yyyy')
console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @GauravChaudhary Hey do you have any ideas how to get the list of last week date?

Comment: @hyperfkcb Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13493709/7549867

Comment: @hyperfkcb `date.getDate() - date.getDay()` will give you last Sunday. You can subtract six times to reach last Monday and find dates for each day

Comment: @GauravChaudhary Yeah sure I figured out how already. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
// returns the first day of the current week  
function getMonday(d) {
  d = new Date(d);
  var day = d.getDay(),
      diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1); // adjust when day is sunday
  return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}

var dayToPrint = getMonday(new Date());
for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
    alert(dayToPrint);
    dayToPrint.setDate(dayToPrint.getDate() + 1);
}
```

I'm not really sure of what you want but the previous code will alert each day of the current week.

Edit :
And in order to have the same format as in your question :

```
var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];

var dayNames = [
    "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",
    "Sunday"
 ];

function getMonday(d) {
    d = new Date(d);
    var day = d.getDay(),
    diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1); // adjust when day is sunday
    return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}

function formatDate(d) {
    return monthNames[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getDate() + "." + d.getFullYear() + " (" + dayNames[i] + ")"
}

var dayToPrint = getMonday(new Date());
for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
    alert(formatDate(dayToPrint));
    dayToPrint.setDate(dayToPrint.getDate() + 1);
}
```